# Trying to take size and input of a list in a single line

Tags: python-3.x, list, input

I want to input 'n+1' numbers from the user in a single line, the first number gives the size of the list, while the following numbers are the actual elements of the list.

```
(n,listA)=(int(input()),list(map(int,input().split())))
```

This works but I have to hit enter after giving the first number (the size) otherwise I get an error. I want this done without enter.
Example - 4 12 43 23 56
So size=4
list=[12,43,23,56]

Comment: You are definitely cramming to much into a single line. I'm pretty sure, that you expect the first `input()` to be the length of the list you are only about to construct later (the split result).Simultaneous assignment is the wrong approach for that.

Comment: Most of time, the input format is fixed for the problem, Which MAY not be the most efficient way to do it. (This was a part of a coding challenge)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you want this for code golfing purposes. This is AFAIK the shortest oneliner that will work:

```
n,*l=map(int,input().split())  # in:  3 6 71 51
print(n)                       # out: 3
print(l)                       # out: [6, 71, 51]
```

Without using semicolons, I think the size of the input can only be restriced in one line using Python 3.8:

```
n,*l=list(map(int,i:=input().split()))[:int(i[0])+1]  # in:  3 6 71 51 80 95
print(n)                                              # out: 3
print(l)                                              # out: [6, 71, 51]
```

Comment: Lists in python can grow as per the input. So, can we restrict the user to enter only the 'size' number of elements, that is, as soon as they enter (size) elements, we implicitly execute 'Enter' ? (that is not wait for them to manually hit enter) @ruohola

Answer (score 0):

```
[[n],listA] = [list(map(int,i.split())) for i in input().split(' ',1)]
```

split(' ',1) will split first occurrence, so an input like 4 12 43 23 56 will split to '4', '12 43 23 56',

then preform another spiting with mapping the output will be `[[4], [12, 43, 23, 56]]`

then we can unpack the value again `[[n],listA]`.

however i suggest to neglect the size from input and taking list of numbers and by using `size = len(listA)` we can determine the size.