# Reverse the given string

Tags: python-3.x

I'm writing a program to print the reverse of a given string. I am able to write the function to reverse the string but not able to take as many inputs as given in the test cases.

I've tried using "while" loop but I'm not able to get all the test cases as input. Maybe the syntax is wrong. I'm a newbie.

```
def rev(sample_string):
    return sample_string[::-1]

t_case = int(input())   #No. of testcases
i = 0

while i < t_case:
    sample_string = str(input(""))    #take as many inputs as no. of 
                                      #testcases 
    i =+ 1

print(rev(sample_string))
```

for sample input: 2, ab, aba --------
output should be: ba, aba           //(in separate lines)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to take size and input of a list in a single line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58235823/trying-to-take-size-and-input-of-a-list-in-a-single-line)

Comment: You're only calling rev once, outside of the loop. Move that inside of the loop and it will print the sample string you're getting from the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to save and print multiple strings, you need a datatype to do so.
List would do that job:

```py
def rev(sample_string):
    return sample_string[::-1]

t_case = int(input())   #No. of testcases
i = 0
string_list = []  # List to store the strings

while i < t_case:
    string_list.append(str(input("")))    #take as many inputs as no. of 
                                      #testcases 
    i += 1

for string in string_list:  # iterate over the list and print the reverse strings
    print(rev(string))
```